# Is the sect of 'the Way' in Acts 24:14 the same as the sect of 'the Nazarenes' in Acts 24:5?

Tags: acts, paul, new-testament, body-of-christ

In Acts 24:14, Paul said that the Jews identifies 'the Way' as a sect.

> 14 But this I confess to you, that according to **the Way, which they
>   call a sect**, I worship the God of our fathers, believing everything
>   laid down by the Law and written in the Prophets, Acts 24:14 (ESV)

However, earlier in the same chapter (v. 5), we read that Paul was a leader of the sect known as 'the Nazarenes.'

> For we have found this man a plague, one who stirs up riots among all
>   the Jews throughout the world and is *a ringleader of* **the sect of
>   the Nazarenes**. Acts 24:5 (ESV)

### Is the sect of 'the Way' in Acts 24:14 the same as the sect of 'the Nazarenes' in Acts 24:5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the sect of 'the Way' is the same as the sect of 'the Nazarenes.'

Peter refers to Jesus as 'of Nazareth' in his sermon in Acts 2:

> “Men of Israel, hear these words: **Jesus of Nazareth**, a Man attested by God to you by miracles, wonders, and signs which God did through Him in your midst, as you yourselves also know—
>   [-Acts 2:22 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+2%3A22&version=NKJV)

And there are quite a few other times where Jesus is associated specifically with Nazareth:

> Then Peter said, “Silver and gold I do not have, but what I do have I give you: In the name of **Jesus Christ of Nazareth**, rise up and walk.” [-Acts 3:6 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+3%3A1-10&version=NKJV)
>
> [Peter speaking:] let it be known to you all, and to all the people of Israel, that by the name of **Jesus Christ of Nazareth**, whom you crucified, whom God raised from the dead... [-Acts 4:10 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+4%3A8-12&version=NKJV)
>
> [False witnesses speaking:] for we have heard him [Stephen] say that this **Jesus of Nazareth** will destroy this place and change the customs which Moses delivered to us. [-Acts 8:14 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+6%3A8-15&version=NKJV)
>
> [Peter speaking to Cornelius:] how God anointed **Jesus of Nazareth** with the Holy Spirit and with power, who went about doing good and healing all who were oppressed by the devil, for God was with Him. [-Acts 10:38 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+10%3A34-43&version=NKJV)
>
> [Paul speaking to King Agrippa:] Indeed, I myself thought I must do many things contrary to the name of **Jesus of Nazareth**. [-Acts 26:9 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+26%3A1-11&version=NKJV)

Acts 9 calls the followers of the Lord 'the Way':

> 1 Then Saul, still breathing threats and murder against the disciples of the Lord, went to the high priest 2 and asked letters from him to the synagogues of Damascus, **so that if he found any who were of the Way**, whether men or women, he might bring them bound to Jerusalem.
>   [-Acts 9:1-2 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+9%3A1-2&version=NKJV)

And Paul, recounting his own conversion on the road to Damascus, associates the 'Way' with Jesus of Nazareth:

> 4 I persecuted **this Way** to the death, binding and delivering into prisons both men and women, [...] 6 “Now it happened, as I journeyed and came near Damascus at about noon, suddenly a great light from heaven shone around me. 7 And I fell to the ground and heard a voice saying to me, ‘Saul, Saul, why are you persecuting Me?’ 8 So I answered, ‘Who are You, Lord?’ And He said to me, **‘I am Jesus of Nazareth**, whom you are persecuting.’
>   [-Acts 22:4, 6-8 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+22%3A1-9&version=NKJV) {Note that Paul's name was 'Saul' at the time of his conversion}

So as you can see, followers of 'the Way' were followers of 'Jesus of Nazareth.' The sect of 'the Way' and the sect of 'the Nazarenes' are one and the same. Those accusing Paul in Acts 24 most likely tried to use this to their advantage, for even Nathanael, whom Jesus called a 'true Israelite indeed,' said in [John 1:46 (NKJV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+1%3A43-49&version=NKJV): "Can anything good come out of Nazareth?"

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.  The “sect” called The Way was the TRUE early church — “to the Jew first and also to the Greek” (Gentiles).  Titus Flavius Josephus, a traitorous Jewish general, paid historian, and self-described Pharisee (Matthew 23), coined the derogatory term “Essenes” applied incorrectly to this day.  Before Essenes was coined, The Way was likewise called “Nazarenes” in a derogatory manner.  This “sect” was formed in the mid second century BCE when the Maccabees/Hasmoneans usurped the office of chief priest from the sons of Zadok.  The most infamous of the Maccabees was John Hyrcanus, who converted the Idumeans/Edomites by the sword to Judaism.  The Herodian dynasty arose from these sons of Esau and usurped the Maccabees.

The Congregation of men and women of The Way resided in Damascus, Syria.  They would send their firstborn sons to Qumran to study.  Those sons of Zadok/priests, other Levites, Israelites, and proselytes where chaste; they are the 144,000 of Revelation.  They also penned the Dead Sea Scrolls and were referenced as the “wise men of the East.”

http://bit.ly/TheWayPennedDSS
http://bit.ly/TheWayInActs
http://bit.ly/DSSCalendarDiscovery